# kibana 6 scripted field dates ranges

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Using kibana 6.3

I created this scripted field to split out just the hours from the 
YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00

hour_utc:

```
doc['@timestamp'].date.hourOfDay
```

Then I can create a filter that does this:

Filter Between 6 to 22 and get only hours 06-22 for whatever date or dates I list. This works great. BUT I also need to be able to do 22 to 6

If date is 01/01/2019 to 01/04/2019 then
filter 6 to 22 gives you this:

```
01/01/2019T06:00:00 to 01/01/2019T22:00:00
01/02/2019T06:00:00 to 01/02/2019T22:00:00
01/03/2019T06:00:00 to 01/03/2019T22:00:00
01/04/2019T06:00:00 to 01/04/2019T22:00:00
```

If date is 01/01/2019 to 01/04/2019 then
filter 22 to 06 gives you this:

```
01/01/2019T22:00:00 to 01/02/2019T06:00:00
01/02/2019T22:00:00 to 01/03/2019T06:00:00
01/03/2019T22:00:00 to 01/04/2019T06:00:00
```

My issue is how do I do 22-06 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create two filters combined in a bool should clause:

- one that does 22 to 24
- one that does 0 to 6

Pseudo query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "hour": {
              "gte": 22
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "hour": {
              "gte": 0,
              "lte": 6
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Another option is to shift your scripted field by 6 hours

```
doc['@timestamp'].date.hourOfDay - 6
```

and then you can simply check that it is between 16 and 24.